# Filter employees by profile_id in back office Employees tab

Tags: sql, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

i try to apply a filter by profile on my tab "employees" in back-office, just need to list the employees with profile_id = 6.

I found this part of code in AdminEmployeesController.php, line 175 to 184 :

```
public function renderList()
{
  $this->_select = 'pl.`name` AS profile ';


$this->_join = 'LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'profile` p ON a.`id_profile` =      p.`id_profile`
LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'profile_lang` pl ON (pl.`id_profile` =  p.`id_profile`  AND pl.`id_lang` = '
.(int)$this->context->language->id.') ';


return parent::renderList();
}
```

but I don't found the correct solution till now; Can somebody help me?

Prestashop 1.6.0.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may modify `_where` variable:

```
$this->_where = 'AND a.`id_profile` = 6';

return parent::renderList();
```

Please dont forget to place your override in overriden class in

`/overrides/controllers/admin/AdminEmployeesController.php`